# Touch ID Issue with Sandbox Purchases

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, in-app-purchase, touch-id

Hi I was wondering if anyone else is having the same issue or has a fix for it.

When i'm trying to make an in app purchase in the sandbox for my app and i try and use touch id, it repeats the touch id alert three times then fails, i've tried using it in apples IAP demo app as well and get the same issue. is this issue only for sandbox mode? or has someone found a way around this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm getting this as well, its really annoying... The only workaround I have found is to turn Touch ID off and on in Settings for the App Store, but the problem comes back after a few days... Any updates on this?

Comment: It seems to be really intermittent! i sometimes get a similar issue with just using the password as well and its been making life harder for my testers. It really messes with the IAP process

Comment: Any news on this? I'm facing the same issue now. Also intermittent and sometimes the error "_You are not authorized to make purchases of this InApp in Sandbox at this time_" comes afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm pretty certain that Touch ID is not supported in the sandbox test environement (sic)" 
>   - Rich Kubota @ Apple.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/43228

I also see the behaviour you describe, and it has been this way for at least a year or two - it seems that TouchID is only supported by the production environment. I could not find any official documentation to support this however - there is no mention of it in, for example, Apple's [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH1-SW1).

Answer (score -1):

This is an issue with iOS. If you have a contact with Apple, be sure to bump it.